# Is "dispersion" a parameter in Gaussian glm?

Tags: normal-distribution, generalized-linear-model, dispersion

Let do a simple glm in R:

```r
> y=rnorm(100)
> gnul <- glm(y ~ 1)
> gnul$coefficients
(Intercept) 
  0.1399966
```

However, of course, as the distribution is Gaussian (with identity link, default), there is a second parameter: the sd parameter. We can see its presence when the log likelihood is displayed:

```r
> logLik(gnul)
'log Lik.' -138.7902 (df=2)
```

ok. All is alright; there are two parameters. 2 parameters are used also if the AIC of the model is calculated.

But what is the value of this parameter? Let do a simple manual fit of this model (the 1E9 factor is just to be sure that the fit is near perfect):

```r
> dnormx <- function(x, data) {1E9*-sum(dnorm(data, mean=x["mean"], sd=x["sd"], log = TRUE))}
> parg <- c(mean=0, sd=1)
> o0 <- optim(par = parg, fn=dnormx, data=y, method="BFGS")
> o0$value/1E9
[1] 138.7902
> o0$par
     mean        sd 
0.1399966 0.9694405
```

The log likelihoods and the fitted parameter are the same. Perfect.

Let see what is the dispersion parameter fitted with glm and its square root:

```r
> summary(gnul)$dispersion
[1] 0.9493079
> sqrt(summary(gnul)$dispersion)
[1] 0.9743243
```

Why is it different from the sd fitted with optim? If I check the function getFromNamespace("summary.glm", ns="stats"), I found that dispersion parameter is estimated using:

```r
> sum(gnul$residuals^2)/gnul$df.residual
[1] 0.9493079
> gnul$df.residual
[1] 99
```

The gnul$df.residual is 99, it means that dispersion parameter is not counted as a fitted parameter (100 is for data and 1 is for mean).

I fail to understand the logic behind the status of the dispersion parameter in this simple glm:

- It is one fitted parameter when optim is used,
- It is one fitted parameter when AIC is estimated,
- It is not counted as a parameter for $df.residual

And finally where is located the "true" sd value that is used to estimate likelihood in glm object? It appears that it is not the square root of the dispersion parameter:

```r
> sum(dnorm(y, mean=gnul$coefficients, sd=sqrt(sum(gnul$residuals^2)/gnul$df.residual), log = TRUE))
[1] -138.7927
> logLik(gnul)
'log Lik.' -138.7902 (df=2)
```

Thanks for any precision that could help me to understand these points,